# Magento import error logs

Tags: magento

I would like to know if magento logs the error rows anywhere when doing an import. 
If so, where are the logs files, and how do I turn it on?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the method definition in app/Mage.php 
you will find

```
  /**
     * log facility (??)
     *
     * @param string $message
     * @param integer $level
     * @param string $file
     * @param bool $forceLog
     */
    public static function log($message, $level = null, $file = '', $forceLog = false)
    {
        if (!self::getConfig()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            $logActive = self::getStoreConfig('dev/log/active');
            if (empty($file)) {
                $file = self::getStoreConfig('dev/log/file');
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $logActive = true;
        }

        if (!self::$_isDeveloperMode && !$logActive && !$forceLog) {
            return;
        }

        static $loggers = array();

        $level  = is_null($level) ? Zend_Log::DEBUG : $level;
        $file = empty($file) ? 'system.log' : $file;

        try {
            if (!isset($loggers[$file])) {
                $logDir  = self::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'log';
                $logFile = $logDir . DS . $file;

                if (!is_dir($logDir)) {
                    mkdir($logDir);
                    chmod($logDir, 0777);
                }

                if (!file_exists($logFile)) {
                    file_put_contents($logFile, '');
                    chmod($logFile, 0777);
                }

                $format = '%timestamp% %priorityName% (%priority%): %message%' . PHP_EOL;
                $formatter = new Zend_Log_Formatter_Simple($format);
                $writerModel = (string)self::getConfig()->getNode('global/log/core/writer_model');
                if (!self::$_app || !$writerModel) {
                    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream($logFile);
                }
                else {
                    $writer = new $writerModel($logFile);
                }
                $writer->setFormatter($formatter);
                $loggers[$file] = new Zend_Log($writer);
            }

            if (is_array($message) || is_object($message)) {
                $message = print_r($message, true);
            }

            $loggers[$file]->log($message, $level);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
        }
    }
```

so logging to your own code, logging becomes as easy as

```
Mage::log($variable, null, 'yourfile.log', 1);
```

The 1 as the fourth option is completely option and supersedes the option of turning the logging off in the admin and will always force the system to write to your log.  Everything for logging is done in HTTP_ROOT/var/log/

Logging is turned on by default, but if you are using a custom extension and need to insert logging, you can do the above.  Any logging by Magento will always be in var/log/exception.log or var/log/system.log but most things will go to system.log unless it is something that uses throwException(), which goes to exception.log

Answer (score 1):

Use direct import of products you will see error row no if any error exists on your screen..
Its fast method to import products

Answer (score 0):

You can active the Exception.log file through Developer config menu.

Answer (score 0):

In magento two file generated for log system.log file and exception.log file both file you find in var/log folder

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting `$_debugMode = true` in the `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Abstract` model but it didn't create any logs in my case. I was uploading products using DataFlow method.

Then what I did was to change the `Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_ProfileController` a litte bit. Inside `batchRunAction()` it generates the errors as

`try {
    $importData = $batchImportModel->getBatchData();
    $adapter->saveRow($importData);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
    continue;
    }`

I logged the `$errors` array along with the current product sku to get what I needed, i.e., 
`Mage::log($importData['sku'].' - '.$e->getMessage())`